# Adicionar um Parent '&' numa variável usando LESS

Tags: less

Estou com um problema mas não sei se é possível, estou querendo editar algumas `class` colocando um `&` segue o exemplo:

```
.bcolor(@prefix, @suffix) {
    .@{prefix}red@{suffix} {
        background-color: red;
    }
    .@{prefix}blue@{suffix} {
        background-color: blue;
    }
}

table {
  &.bcolor {
    .bcolor(bc-, ~">tbody>tr");
  }
}
```

Aqui tudo bem mas a resposta é essa:

```
table.bcolor .bc-red>tbody>tr {
  background-color: red;
}
table.bcolor .bc-blue>tbody>tr {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Eu precisaria que a resposta assim:

```
table.bcolor.bc-red>tbody>tr {
  background-color: red;
}
table.bcolor.bc-blue>tbody>tr {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Mas toda vez que adiciono `&` numa variável ele da erro, segue o exemplo:

```
table {
  &.bcolor {
    &.bcolor(bc-, ~">tbody>tr");
  }
}
```